# MySQL - Duplicate parent column value on insertion

Tags: php, mysql, database

Let's say I have three tables:

#### categories

```
| column | data_type   |
|--------|-------------|
| id     | int(10)     |
| code   | int(5)      |
| name   | varchar(50) |
```

#### deposits

```
| column | data_type   |
|--------|-------------|
| id     | int(10)     |
| code   | int(5)      |
| name   | varchar(50) |
```

#### items

```
| column        | data_type   |
|---------------|-------------|
| id            | int(10)     |
| category_id   | int(10)     |
| deposit_id    | int(10)     |
| category_code | int(5)      |
| deposit_code  | int(5)      |
| name          | varchar(50) |
```

The `{parent}_id` columns are foreign key constraints. The `{parent}_code` are regular columns that should matches in parent table records.

So, for some reasons I have to insert the same `code` (referent to parent `id`) on `items` table. Actually I'm running a bunch of `select` statements on execution time (PHP app) before running the `insert` statement. Something like:

```
// Begin transaction...
$categoryCode = Category::selectCode($categoryId);
$depositCode = Deposit::selectCode($depositId);

try {
  $item = Item::insert([
    'category_id' => $categoryId,
    'deposit_id' => $depositId,
    'category_code' => $categoryCode,
    'deposit_code' => $depositCode,
    'name' => $name,
  ]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Rolling back...
}
// Commiting...
```

This slows down the process and don't ensures the integrities based on `code` columns.

I'm newbie with SQL but I think that a better approach would be filling these columns automatically right on `insert` statement. How to duplicate the `{parent}_code` columns on `items` child's table?

Comment: Really you are breaking one of the Relational Database rule here. There is no need to store the `category_code, deposit_code` in the items table as it is duplicating the data.

Comment: @RiggsFolly `items.name` is only for `items`, not duplicated

Comment: Ok, so deleted that comment, but the first one stands

Comment: @RiggsFolly of course I know that I'm breaking relational rules but the question isn't about data normalization.

Comment: When you want the category name or the deposits name all you do is JOIN to the relevant table when you want to present the data using the `id`'s you have in the item table row

Comment: @RiggsFolly nice. can you answer with some example of doing this for `code` columns?

Comment: You could use a prepared query with a nested select : `INSERT INTO items (category_id, deposit_id, category_code, deposit_code, name) VALUES ($category_id, $deposit_id, (SELECT code FROM categories WHERE id = $category_id), (SELECT code FROM deposits WHERE id = $deposit_id), "Lorem ipsum")` but with PDO of course. It could speed up the process but will not ensure integrity.

Comment: Well if you agree these 2 lines are not required `'category_code' => $categoryCode, 'deposit_code' => $depositCode,` then you dont need to run the 2 previous fetches

Comment: @Ianis WHY. That data IS NOT REQUIRED in the items table

Comment: @RiggsFolly `code` columns are required! I need to duplicate them. I think that Ianis's approach is valid and I will try it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know that it is not the best way. But : "for some reasons I have to". Alexandre, have you tried to do it with a View ?

Comment: [@huhushow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55047557/1288121) has probably the best answer for what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

basically, you don't need {parent}_code in items table. but sometime, it is needed.
if you really need those, you can do 'insert into select' instead 'insert into values()'
queri looks like this

```
INSERT INTO items (category_id, deposit_id, category_code, deposit_code, name)
SELECT c.category_id, d.deposit_id, c.category_code, d.category_code, {name_val}
FROM categories as c JOIN deposits as d 
  ON (c.category_id= {c_id} and d.deposit_id= {d_id})
```

this is simple cross join whti specific id value. IO cost may same as separate multiple query. but this reduces execution count. and it will reduces the total execution time.

Comment: This is probably the best way as per OP's use case.

Answer (score 1):

The `category_code` and `deposit_code` are not required in the items table.

So your example code becomes

```
// Begin transaction...
//$categoryCode = Category::selectCode($categoryId);
//$depositCode = Deposit::selectCode($depositId);

try {
  $item = Item::insert([
    'category_id' => $categoryId,
    'deposit_id' => $depositId,
    'name' => $name,
  ]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Rolling back...
}
// Commiting...
```

When you want to see the `category_code` and `deposit_code` of this item you just JOIN the tables using the `category_id` and `deposit_id`

```
SELECT i.name as item_name, c.category_code, d.deposit_code, ....
FROM item i
    JOIN category c ON c.id = i.category_id
    JOIN deposit d ON d.id = i.deposit_id
WHERE .......
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Let's say I have two tables : Product (id, name, price) and Order (id, product_id, product_price). Product.price might change so I need to store it in the Order.product_price to allow the user to see how much he paid. How would a Join help ? (please dont talk about logging all the price change)

Comment: @Ianis I think what you say makes sense! However that is not what the question asked. There is no reference to price in fact all the OP is talking about is a CODE

Comment: If I read the answer as you did I would suggest to delete the code column, there is already an Id column and code is also an integer. So while your point is valid Alexandre's goal is to  "Duplicate parent column value on insertion"

There are constraints that we are not aware of.